# how to refresh images on browser "BACK"?

Tags: php, html

I am going to need my page to refresh an image when the user hits the browsers back button.
It is a captcha and for some reason upon 'back' the page is loading the old captcha, which code will no longer work.

I tried adding the `<img src="captcha.jpg?"<?php echo time(); ?> />`, but surely, the image was found in the cache. (we loaded it a few seconds ago :))

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use php headers too it will help u alot

```
   header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT"); 
   header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");       
   header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

and html tags too

```
   <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="0">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-store">
```

Comment: if these are supposed to be on the page that should reload upon 'back', then this solution doesn't make my browsers reload the page. All I can see is that it refreshes the php page but not the image

Answer (score 2):

You can use: **[cache-control using http-equiv meta tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp)**,

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```

in your ***page head tag***.

This will force browser not to view cached content. and generate a request to origin and bring the results on new request.

You can further look into this here: http://www.metatags.org/meta_http_equiv_cache_control
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ok just as a suggestion:

with javascript you can detect the back button clicked see this topic: http://www.bajb.net/2010/02/browser-back-button-detection/

Then in the code that manages the event do the ajax call or whatever you need to update your image

Answer (score 1):

Use the `window.onpageshow` event on the client side and refresh the CAPTCHA with AJAX.